# Replacement for CMake: LOCATION_<CONFIG>

Tags: cmake

I am a happy user of `LOCATION_<CONFIG>` target property. I've been using it for a while now:

```
foreach(cfg ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES})
  get_target_property(library_dll ${library} LOCATION_${cfg})
  string(REPLACE .dll .pdb library_pdb ${library_dll})
  string(TOLOWER ${cfg} lcfg)
  if(lcfg STREQUAL "debug" OR lcfg STREQUAL "relwithdebinfo")
    install (FILES ${library_pdb}
      DESTINATION ${GDCM_INSTALL_BIN_DIR}
      COMPONENT DebugDevel
      CONFIGURATIONS ${cfg}
      )
  endif()
endforeach()
```

See:

- https://github.com/malaterre/GDCM/blob/master/CMake/InstallMacros.cmake#L61-L75

This was documented from the bug tracker:

- https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=11671#c24538

However an external project wants to use:

```
if(POLICY CMP0026)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0026 NEW)
endif()
```

Which means I am forced to find an alternative to my old `LOCATION_<CONFIG>` target property solution.

What is the proper way to rewrite this macro in current CMake (where `CMP0026 NEW`) to avoid the following error ?

```
CMake Error at CMake/InstallMacros.cmake:65 (get_target_property):
The LOCATION property may not be read from target "gdcmCommon". Use the
target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator
expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
Source/Common/CMakeLists.txt:219 (install_pdb)
```

Comment: According to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), generator expression `$<TARGET_PDB_FILE:tgt>` contains full path to the `.pdb` file for the target. Is it what you seek?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce - as @Tsyvarev commented - to

```
if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  install (
      FILES           "$<TARGET_PDB_FILE:${library}>"
      DESTINATION     "${GDCM_INSTALL_BIN_DIR}"
      COMPONENT       DebugDevel
      CONFIGURATIONS  Debug RelWithDebInfo
  )
endif()
```

by using [informational generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#informational-expressions).